# Multiplication in Laravel controller not getting the multiplied data in sql

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I have a question that why my calculated data not getting properly inside my SQL databse.
I'm getting data when i use * to multiply product  price. Please check my code

I need to get the multiplied value as product price inside my database.

```
public function add_cart(Request $request, $id){
        if(Auth::id()){
            $user=Auth::user();
            $product=product::find($id);
            $cart = new cart;


            $cart->name=$user->name;
            $cart->email=$user->email;
            $cart->phone=$user->phone;
            $cart->address=$user->address;
            $cart->user_id=$user->id;
            $cart->product_id=$product->id;
            $cart->product_title=$product->title;
            $cart->quantity=$request->quantity;
            if($product-> discount_price=!null){
                $cart->price= $product->discount_price * $request->quantity;
            }
            else{
                $cart->price= $product->price * $request->quantity;
            }
            
            $cart->image=$product->image;
            

            $cart->save();
            return redirect()->back();

        }
        else{
            return redirect('login');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please download an intelligent IDE such as PHP storm or Netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

There are some several things I found in your code.
First of all =! does not work in your if statement. You need to use != instead.

And second of all there is a space between -> and your property. I guess these will help your code work properly.

I wish it was helpful for you:)

Comment: Your welcome. I would be happier if you vote my answer up too:)❤️